# Why do I get a CORS error in an XmlHttpRequest

Tags: django, vue.js, xmlhttprequest, cors

Since removing and reinstalling Python due to issues with my environment, I am now getting a CORS error during an XMLHttpRequest:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:8000/admin/login/?next=/api/report_builder/api/fields' (redirected from 'localhost:8000/api/report_builder/api/fields') from origin 'localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

The backend is Django, and the frontend is Vue.js. I have not changed anything with the code since before the error.

Any suggestions?

[image: Screenshot of page and error]

Comment: Please post some links, screenshots, example code, configuration etc that would help resolving the problem. Currently, there's nothing to go by to help resolve your issue

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/admin/login/?next=/api/report_builder/api/fields' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8000/api/report_builder/api/fields') from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response. this is the error showing

Answer (score -1):

It seems the issue was with the nginx and Gunicorn configuration as i was using windows pc i didn't install and configure that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).